# Is fetching data from database a get-method thing?

Tags: php, database, oop

I have a small class that I call Viewer. This class is supposed to view the proper layout of each page or something like that...

I have a method called getFirstPage, when called the user of this method will get a setting value for which page is currently set as the first page. I have some code here, I think it works but I am not really shure that I have done it the right way:

```
class Viewer {

private $db;
private $user;
private $firstPage;

function __construct($db, $user) {

    $this->db = $db;

    if(isset($user)) {
        $this->user = $user;
    } else {
        $this->user = 'default';
    }
}

function getFistPage() {
    $std = $db->prepare("SELECT firstPage FROM settings WHERE user = ':user'");
    $std->execute(array(':user' => $user));
    $result = $std->fetch();
    $this->firstPage = $result['firstPage'];

    return $this->firstPage;
}
}
```

My get method is fetching the setting from databse (so far so good?). The problem is that then I have to use this get method to set the private variable firstPage. It seems like I should have a set method to do this, but I cannot really have a set method that just fetch some setting from database, right? Because the user of this object should be able to assume that there already is a setting defined in the object...

How should I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your approach is not bad. The most important thing is passing `$db` in the constructor, which you do. The user could be parameter of the constructor or the method itself, it depends on how 'permanent' the user is, for the application.

There are several minor things I would improve:

1. Use type hinting for PDO object. Therefore, anyone who uses your 'library' knows what kind of object should be injected.
2. Almost never use `private` visibility, use `protected` instead. Therefore, if someone wants to extend your class, he still has access to your properties.
3. Don't use isset/empty for checking $user, rather introduce a default value. Therefore, anyone who calls your method and sees the parameters knows, what's going on.
4. Always explicitly use `public` visibility. It's a good practice and you won't confuse for example Java developers, who have `package` as default.
5. If you really want to create a high quality code, check for every possible error state so you won't encounter a fatal error. `PDO::fetch` can return false and you should check this error state before you access the result as an array.
6. If you decide to save `$firstPage` to the object state, you should reuse it the next time the method is called. However, if you write a common web app, I don't think you really want to put it to object state. Instead, just return the result.

Then, your code would look like this:

```
class Viewer {

  /** @var PDO $db */
  protected $db;
  protected $user;

  public function __construct(PDO $db, $user = 'default') {  
    $this->db = $db;
    $this->user = $user;
  }

  public function getFistPage() {
    $std = $this->db->prepare("SELECT firstPage FROM settings WHERE user = ':user'");
    $std->execute(array(':user' => $this->user));
    $result = $std->fetch();

    if ($result !== false) {
      return $result['firstPage'];
    } else {
      throw new YourException('Failed to fetch first page.');
      // or return false/null;
  }
}
```

Edit: You should always fully set up the object state in the constructor and you should not do any computation in it. Also, avoid using initialize-like methods. In this case, constructor ensures we have PDO and `$user` parameter set up (object state). Then, you can do your computation in the method without passing additional parameters (which is good, it supports object encapsulation).

Comment: I totally forgot about the public keyword when writing the method! My first thaught was to initalize all the values (there is supposed to be more than just firstPage) in the constructor but then I read that you should not do that. How should I do if I want to initialize more than one parameter at the time? Could I write a initialize method?

Comment: Initialize method is considered to be a bad practice. You should just set the object state in the constructor and do all the computation in the methods. Why do you want to initialize `firstPage` before you call `getFirstPage` method?

Comment: The object as a viewer depend on the current users setting, therefore the object as an instance would not be complete without firstPage set.

Comment: "Complete" object does not have to contain all necessary information - and it should not. It must only know a WAY to get the information/calculation when necessary. If I create an object for parsing XML, I do not inject the whole XML in the constructor. I just specify tools for parsing XML and I prepare WAY to do so when it's actually necessary.

Comment: How should I throw the exception? Should I wrap the throw statement in a try, catch block? Because php is complaining if I just write it like that.

Answer (score 1):

Getters should not change the state of the object. However, sometimes member variables are not part of the actual object state - rather they are used for internal caching. You should ask yourself - is `firstPage` part of the state? Should users of the class care whether it was set or not? Other than performance, does the object act differently based on it's value? If not, than it's OK to set it in a getter.